# Page WYSWIG only allowing slides

Tags: gallery, frontpage, slideshow

How do I add other content to my homepage.It is only accepting image slider.
I would like to add some raw html and a gallery below the slides.Removing all images in the slides doesnt reveal the normal editor.
[image: homepage]

My frontpage.php is as below in case it may be the culprit.

```
   <?php get_header(); ?>

        <div class="home-content">
            <div class="carousel" id="home-carousel">
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php while(have_rows('slides')): the_row(); ?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <div class="carousel-slide" id="carousel-slide-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="<?php echo get_slide_style(get_sub_field('image')); ?>">
                        <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>" class="carousel-slide-link"></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-nav clearfix" id="home-carousel-nav">
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                <?php while(have_rows('slides')): the_row(); ?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('link'); ?>" class="carousel-nav-item carousel-nav-<?php echo $i; ?> <?php echo $i === 1 ? 'here' : ''; ?>" id="carousel-nav-<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php the_sub_field('title'); ?></a>
                <?php endwhile; ?>      

          <div>add gallery here</div>
      </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Does that show you adding Products - custom post type? If you're adapting a theme, what is it called? Is the actual page set to use a custom template? Is it 'widgetised' (add widgets to add more content - Woo Commerce documentation should tell you)?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the editor was hidden using advanced custom fields plugin.